# Display only specific attachments

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to list the attachments of a list item depending on it's name. But I have no idea how to get the name attribute into the if condition:

```
<xsl:if test="????????">
  <xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
      <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>                        
      <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
         <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

Who can help me?

Comment: how do you want to fetch list attachments ? OOTB webpart or custom webpart ? it seems you are either trying to use content query or dataview webpart.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I created a new form for showing the list item in the SharePoint Designer. Then I adjusted the code and added the line above. The code is working and shows the attached documents. The if-clause is working for other attributes, but I don't know how to get the name of the document element